# Powershell recursive function - how to tell what level I'm at?

Tags: powershell, recursion

I have this code that returns information about TFS WorkItems. I stripped out TFS specific stuff to reduce noise. At the end of the day it's a recursive function that starts with a root and walks down a tree as long it finds children. I'd like to add some logic to format the output differently depending on a level. May be adding a tab to each line, or some other way of visually identifying each level, is there something like `if ($$some_variable -eq 1) {write-host "welcome to level 1"}`?
here is the powershell code:

```
   $wi_id = 123
$result=@()

function get_linkedWIs  {
param($wi_id)
$WIT.GetWorkItem($wi_id) |%{ $_.WorkItemLinks} |?{$_.LinkTypeEnd.Name -eq "Child" } | %{$result +=$WIT.GetWorkItem($_.targetid)}

$result.GetEnumerator()  | Sort -Property id -Unique 
}

function get_children {
param($wi_id)
$rs = get_linkedWIs $wi_id
$rs | %{
Write-Host "this is a num - "$script:num

write-host $_.Type.Name" "$_.id" "$_.Title
$has_children = 0
$_.WorkItemLinks | %{if ($_.LinkTypeEnd.Name -eq "Child" -or $has_children -eq 1) {$has_children =1} }
if ($has_children -eq 1)
{
$script:num +=1
get_children $_.id 
}
}

}


get_children $wi_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure ... pass a `level` variable in the parameter list.  The main program calls with value 1.  When the function recurs, call with value `$level+1`.  That way, every instance has a local variable holding the call level.

You can also do this with a global variable, adding 1 on entry and subtracting 1 on exit, but that's not as safe.

Comment: that would work fine if every node had exactly one child, but that obviously isn't the case.  so, let's we have a "feature" which is level 1, followed by "user story" which is level 2. Using your suggestion, each time this function is called for a "user story" a level indicator would be incremented, but it shouldn't. Only when "user story" child work item is processed should a level increment to 3. Makes sense?

Comment: In my first suggestion, the "feature" node calls each of its children with `$level+1`; do not increment the local value, just pass one more to the child.  Each "user story" child gets the *same* incremented value.  Your description seems to imply that "level increase" and "child" are not equivalent.  Please post a description of your tree structure.

Comment: thanks, no, they are equivalent. I was just adding the $level+1 inside the loop that makes the recursive call. I had a feeling it was something simple.